# Nothing is unwraping in the UV window. As you can see below, i have everything selected and when i then select "unwrap" nothing happens

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I dont know what´s happening. When i did it a cupple of minutes ago i at least got a map. (it was wrong and wierd looking though). Im following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPoxqOcUzNQ) and i marked the exact seams they did and it looked sooo wrong. idk, everyting layed on top of eatchother and i couldn´t see what whas what. Then i deselected everyting and started ofer and now nothing works.
please help!

!!Update!!
It was the "show overlay" that was the problem. However it stil looks wierd to me. Why does it look like this? (it didn´t in the tutorial)[image]

Comment: Hello :). You have no faces selected. You need to select the faces you want to unwrap.

Comment: thank you, that didn´t work either though

Comment: Your image shows that you have nothing selected in the edit window. With the mouse in that window, press 'A' then try unwrapping again.

Comment: everytig is selected. I tried to unwrap the apple again (witch have worked before) and it didn´t work either.

Comment: I highly recommended you to open a new topic for your second question seen that the original is already answered. and that will also help you to have a better answer. But basically it looks like overlapping faces.

Answer (score 0):

You have "Show overlays" turn it Off"

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked :)